# System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'speak' on type 'SpVoice' not found.'

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to run sapi voice texttospeech and received the error.Any look?I have added Imports System.Speech.Synthesis.

```
    sapi = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    sapi.speak("A as an apple")
```

Comment: Why do you think importing a .NET namespace would be of any use when using an unmanaged speech library? Are you trying to use the .NET speech library or not? If you're trying to use the unmanaged SAPI library, the first question is "why", when there is a managed alternative. Assuming you have a good reason to use it at all, is there a good reason that you're using late binding instead of referencing the library directly?

Comment: For future reference, don't submit your question if your code formatting is a mess. A preview is provided for a reason. Look at it, format your question properly and only then submit it.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. what is other alternate?pls advise

Comment: If you're writing .NET code then, unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, you should be using the .NET speech library. That means actually using the types in the `System.Speech.Synthesis` namespace. If that's what you want to do, you need to research how to do it. If you are sticking with the unmanaged SAPI library then that's fine but then importing .NET namespaces whose members you're not using is utterly useless.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works in a .NET Framework project but not in a .NET Core project. When you create a project, if you select (.NET) then that will target .NET 5.0 by default, which is .NET Core. If you want to target .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier then you have to actually select (.NET Framework) when you create a project. If you want to stick with .NET Core then you will need to investigate why there is some difference in creating this COM object in .NET Core. Otherwise, just switch to .NET Framework

Comment: Great info. Thanks for responding. I have added Microsoft speech object library from project menu and then selected com add reference. For VB, I have added imports speechLib and coded as sapi = New SpVoice

sapi.speak("A is for apple ", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault)

Comment: That last comment is unrelated to the topic of this question. Keep your questions specific. Do your research, make your best attempt and then ask a specific question if you encounter a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested using SAPI via a reference in .NET 5.0, rather than late binding, and it worked. It's much better to use early binding if you can anyway. I suggest that you turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties, so early binding is enforced, and also turn it `On` in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects.

Once that's done, open the *References* page of the project properties and add a new reference. Select *Browse*, navigate to *C:\Windows\System32\Speech\Common* and select *sapi.dll*. That will add a reference to *Interop.SpeechLib* to your project. You can now access types and members in that library with full Intellisense support, just as for .NET libraries.

You can then import the `SpeechLib` namespace and then convert your code to use early binding:

```vb
Dim sapi As SpVoice
```

and:

```vb
sapi = New SpVoice
sapi.Speak("A as an apple")
```

Having said all that, especially if you're going to use .NET 5.0 - the latest and greatest version of .NET - you really shouldn't be using an old, unmanaged speech library when .NET provides a managed option. You should be adding the *System.Speech* NuGet package to your project and using the functionality it provides. I won't explain that here because it's beyond the scope of this topic but you ought to look into it.

Comment: system speech is not supported in net core 5 SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

Comment: @Kaur, of course it is. I just tested it myself to prove it. Let me guess: you didn't add the NuGet package despite my specifically saying that you need to in my answer above.

Comment: Yes, I did added system speech Nuget package. I created my project in asp.net core web app. Which template did you use ? Would you be able to share your code? Thx

Comment: This is the first you have mentioned about this being a web app. I was testing in a WinForms app. I have no idea what the implications of using text-to-speech over the web are. In a web app, your VB code is executed on a server and everything at the client end has to be done in HTML and/or JavaScript, so it's a completely different environment. That's why it is important to provide such information at the outset.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I am not able to find WinForms app. It shows included in preview feature but it is not showing in template. Any recommendations how to include WinForms App?

Comment: It seems bizarre that you're just jumping back and forth between a web app and a Windows app to begin with. What type of app are you trying to create? Select a project template appropriate to that. If you are using the latest VS 2019 and you have installed the Windows workload then the .NET 5 WinForms project template will be available. This question is not about how to use VS so how to use VS is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. I already created a project for learning alphabet in Punjabi language by using VB.Now, I want to implement texttospeech features.  SpVoice works fine for English alphabet. I tested.  As you suggested, I should use managed code. so now , I am creating new one to implement texttospeech in multi language. I tried asp.net core Web app, System speech doesn't supported. As you said , It works in NET 5 WinForm. I am trying to locate WinForm template featured.

Comment: You can ask a question about that if you need to but it needs to be separate to this question because it is an unrelated topic.

Comment: I don't see how the unmanaged SAPI or the managed System.Speech could be used in a web app directly anyway. If you really wanted text-to-speech in a web app, you'd probably need something like [this](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/). Presumably those browsers that support it would then interact with SAPI or System.Speech on a Windows machine and some other speech engine on another OS.